# Export Web Map Task for 3076 features

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I am trying to use [Export Web Map Task](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task) but it has a limit of 1000 records, how can I use this service or replicate this service to execute my print command.

Any suggestions? I am working on ArcServer 10 not 10.1 and so cannot use the print task and print widget.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have admin access to the map service? If so, then you should be able to configure the 'Maximum number of records returned by the server' on the service Parameters page. Either thru ArcCatalog desktop app or the Server Manager web app. I have not used 10.0 but was this was in 9.X, and is this way in 10.1.